# User Registration And MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

Rather a basic question, though i'm a bit confused with the architecture.
I am programming a website using Yii framework.
There is a SiteController and AdminController (built not by me).
All the site administration is in AdminController, and the user interaction in SiteController.
I know it is not correct as it is not model-based.

Now, I want to implement user registration.  The user can signup and administrator can change his properties.
Is it better to build UserController or manage all the above in the existing controller (not breaking previous logic)?

Comment: I ll suggest you to check one of the extension available for user management. The code will give you an idea how its implemented by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### By MVC standards its best to split controllers by function groups.

#### Auth Controller

handles authentication/registration/deletion. Sets session vars for logins which all other controllers check first thing.

```
function register(){
}
function logout(){
}
function edit(){
}
function login(){
}
```

#### Admin Controller

handles all administrative tasks

#### User Controller

handles all user tasks. Maybe editing profiles, or posting to a personal blog?

#### Front Controller

handles all public facing tasks, displaying non auth based pages etc.

---

#### Unrelated, CodeIgniter Example

I use this methodology in my CI projects. This information will vary from Yii framework but it gives you a glimpse of a proper MVC setup.

I have core controllers such as:

`application/core/FRONT_Controller.php`
this controller extends CI_Controller and handles all the setup of my pub facing pages. All of my public facing controllers extend FRONT_Controller instead of CI_Controller.

`application/core/USER_Controller.php`
this controller handles all of my users authentication.

`application/core/ADMIN_Controller.php`
this controller does preliminary checks, again all of my admin based controllers extend this controller so the authentication fires off right away... IE:

```
if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()){
        redirect(site_url('/user/login/'));
    }else{
        $this->data['user'] = array(
            'user_id' => $this->tank_auth->get_user_id(),
            'username' => $this->tank_auth->get_username(),
            'emailAddress' => $this->tank_auth->get_email(),
            'firstname' => $this->tank_auth->get_firstname(),
            'lastname' => $this->tank_auth->get_lastname(),
            'userlevel' => $this->tank_auth->get_userlevel(),
            'avatar' => $this->tank_auth->get_avatar(),
            'last_login' => $this->tank_auth->get_last_login()
        );
    }
```

`application/controllers/blog.php:`

```
class Categories extends ADMIN_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

} #end constructor function
```

Answer (score 0):

The users details will be stored in a table, i.e. tbl_users. Creating a model for these users and the relative controller is the right approach with Yii.

You will have a model **user.php** with the rules of validation, the link to the dbtable

You will have a controller **UserController.php** with all the actions relative to this model and the relative access rules.

What I use normally is an actionRegister() in **SiteController.php** overriding the UserController that you can use for admin purpose or not using at all.

So you will have something like:

yousite.com?r=site/register or yoursite.com/register/ if you use a url rewrite